# Clean way to write complex multi-line string to a variable

Tags: bash

I need to write some complex xml to a variable inside a bash script. The xml needs to be readable inside the bash script as this is where the xml fragment will live, it's not being read from another file or source.

So my question is this if I have a long string which I want to be human readable inside my bash script what is the best way to go about it?

Ideally I want:

- to not have to escape any of the characters
- have it break across multiple lines making it human readable
- keep it's indentation

Can this be done with EOF or something, could anyone give me an example?

e.g.

```
String = <<EOF
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <painting>
   <img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
   <caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
 </painting>
EOF
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you're just going to dump that data into a stream again.  Why store it in a variable when you could make things more complex and use streams?

Comment: see this too: [Multi-line string with extra space (preserved indentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929235/multi-line-string-with-extra-space-preserved-indentation)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This will put your text into your variable without needing to escape the quotes. It will also handle unbalanced quotes (apostrophes, i.e. `'`). Putting quotes around the sentinel (EOF) prevents the text from undergoing parameter expansion. The `-d''` causes it to read multiple lines (ignore newlines). `read` is a Bash built-in so it doesn't require calling an external command such as `cat`.

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' String <<"EOF"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <painting>
   <img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
   <caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
 </painting>
EOF
```

Comment: I think avoiding `cat` is not an advantage here. At least you save some characters by using it. ;)

Comment: `cat` is an external command. Not using it saves doing that. Plus, some have the philosophy that if you're using cat with fewer than two arguments "Ur doin' it wrong" (which is distinct from "useless use of `cat`").

Comment: This doesn't work for me unless I put a space between `-d` and `''` -- presumably because it doesn't realize there's an empty string after `-d` unless it's technically a separate parameter.  This may also depend on what version of bash you have (I'm using 3.2.17 under Mac OS X v10.5.8).

Comment: You're right about the `-d` needing a space after it. I may have typo'd that. I've fixed it now.

Comment: and never ever indent second EOF.... (multiple table to head bangs involved)

Comment: Halas, this solution doesn't allow variable substitution like ${foo}...

Comment: @Offirmo: Hence my third sentence.

Comment: I tried to use the above statement while `set -e`. It seems `read` always returns non-zero. You can thick this behaviour by using `! read -d .......`

Comment: @krissi: You should [never use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) `set -e` - it's an archaic relic. Use proper error handling.

Comment: @krissi: read returns non-zero in this case because it encounters end-of-file before the (non-existent) delimiter.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: "Proper" error handling in shell is prohibitively tedious.  `set -e` is imperfect and lays the occasional trap, but makes scripts far more reliable.

Comment: @Andrew: reliable until it isn't

Comment: this solution doesn't preserve leading spaces in the first line of the text. For example, try adding a few spaces before `<?xml version`. The `cat` solution works though.

Comment: You could use `IFS= read -d'' String << "EOF"` to preserve leading space in the first line of the text.

Comment: @krissi: You could use `read -d '' String <<"EOF" ||:` to avoid the error trap.

Comment: But I <3 cat :(

Comment: And if you are using this multi-line `String` variable to write to a file, put the variable around "QUOTES" like `echo "${String}" > /tmp/multiline_file.txt` or `echo "${String}" | tee /tmp/multiline_file.txt`. Took me more than an hour to find that.

Comment: Can I still reference bash variables inside of this?

Comment: @OldBunny2800: "Putting quotes around the sentinal (EOF) prevents the text from undergoing parameter expansion."

Comment: Even though the desire to avoid running external commands is understandable `cat` is still much safer option. I can see at least two issues in the provided examples: losing leading spaces and backslashes. To solve the first one IFS should be changed by `IFS=''`. For the second one `-r` should be used: `read -r -d '' ...`

Comment: Be sure to `echo "$String"` in quotes to inspect your work or newlines won't print.

Comment: `read` didn't work for me at all. I'll try this again at some point.

Answer (score 42):

You've been almost there. Either you use **cat** for the assembly of your string or you quote the whole string (in which case you'd have to escape the quotes inside your string):

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR1=$(cat <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<painting>
  <img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
  <caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
  <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
</painting>
EOF
)

VAR2="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<painting>
  <img src=\"madonna.jpg\" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
  <caption>This is Raphael's \"Foligno\" Madonna, painted in
  <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
</painting>"

echo "${VAR1}"
echo "${VAR2}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the apostrophe in "Raphael's" makes the first one not work.

Comment: Both assignments work for me eventually. The single quote in VAR1 should not be a problem (at least not for bash). Maybe you have been misled by the syntax highlighting?

Comment: It works in a script, but not at a Bash prompt. Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: It is better to quote EOF as `'EOF'` or `"EOF"`, otherwise shell variables will be parsed.

Comment: Be sure to `echo "$VAR1"` with quotes to inspect your work or newlines will not print.

Answer (score 21):

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR1=`cat <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<painting>
  <img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
  <caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
  <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
</painting>
EOF
`
echo "VAR1: ${VAR1}"
```

This should work fine within Bourne shell environment

Comment: +1 this solution allow variable substitution like ${foo}

Comment: Upside: sh-compatible.  Downside: backticks are deprecated/discouraged in bash.  Now if I had to choose between sh and bash...

Comment: since when are backticks deprecated/discouraged? just curious

Comment: @AlexanderMills https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2006

Answer (score 6):

#### Yet another way to do the same...

I like to use variables and special `<<-` who drop *tabulation* at begin of each lines to permit script indentation:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile Pattern <<-eof
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <painting>
          <img src="%s" alt='%s'/>
          <caption>%s, painted in
          <date>%s</date>-<date>%s</date>.</caption>
        </painting>
        eof

while IFS=";" read file alt caption start end ;do
    printf "${Pattern[*]}" "$file" "$alt" "$caption" "$start" "$end"
  done <<-eof
        madonna.jpg;Foligno Madonna, by Raphael;This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna;1511;1512
        eof
```

**warning**: there is no *blank space* before `eof` but only *tabulation*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <painting>
   <img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
   <caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>
 </painting>
```

Some explanations:

- mapfile read entire *here document* in an array.
- the syntaxe `"${Pattern[*]}"` do cast this array into a string.
- I use `IFS=";"` because there is no `;` in required strings
- The syntaxe `while IFS=";" read file ...` prevent `IFS` to be modified for the rest of the script. In this, only `read` do use the modified `IFS`.
- no fork.

Comment: Note that `mapfile` requires Bash 4 or higher. And the syntax `"${Pattern[*]}"` casts the array into a string *when in quotes* (as shown in the example code).

Comment: Yes, bash 4 was very *new* when this question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many corner cases in many of the other answers.

To be absolutely sure there are no issues with spaces, tabs, IFS etc., a better approach is to use the "heredoc" construct, but encode the contents of the heredoc using `uuencode` as explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896025/#11379627.